# One-sided limit of a bounded and decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, monotone-functions

**Question**

> Let $X \subset \mathbb R$ and let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a decreasing function. Let $a\in X'_+$. Show that
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f(x)=L,$$
> where $L=\sup\{f(x):  x>a; x\in X\}$.

---

**My attempt**

Under the given conditions, define $L=\sup\{f(x): x>a; x\in X\}$. We will show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f(x)=L$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Define
$$A=\{f(x): x>a; x\in X\}.$$
Then $L=\sup A$. Since $L$ is the supremum of $A$, $L−ϵ$ is not an upper bound of $A$. Thus there is $y∈A$ so that
$L−ϵ<f(y)$. Define $\delta =y-a$. Then $0<x-a<\delta\Rightarrow a<x<y=a+\delta$. Since $f$ is decreasing, then $L−ϵ<f(y)<f(x)\le L<L+\epsilon$. Thus, if $a<x<y=a+\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f(x)=L$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What does the notation $X_+'$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually incorrect. You will need both inequalities
$$\tag{1} f(x)< L + \epsilon$$
and
$$\tag{2} L-\epsilon < f(x),$$
to conclude $|f(x) - L |<\epsilon$, but you have only the first. The one you proved is (1) and it uses only the property that $L$ is an upper bound of $A$ (so you have $f(x) \le L$), so you haven't used that it is the supremum of $A$, and you haven't used that $f$ is decreasing.

The correct argument is: for all $\epsilon >0$, since $L$ is the supremum of $A$, $L-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A$. Thus there is $y\in A$ so that
$$ L-\epsilon < f(y).$$

From there you can choose $\delta$ as you did to conclude (using that $f$ is decreasing, of course).

Comment: Oh, I get it. Just edited. Does it look ok now?

Comment: Yes, it is correct now.